# What's the best way to release objective-c properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, properties

I'm new to memory-management, and am reading different things about how to best release properties.

If I have:
in .h:

```
@property(retain) NSString *myStr;
```

and in .m:

```
@synthesize myStr = _iVarStr;
```

Should my dealloc have:

```
[_iVarStr release];
```

or

```
self.myStr = nil;
```

or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: On a related note, try to use the 'nonatomic' property wherever possible.  According to Apple, it can result in significant performance improvements (at the cost of some risk if you get into multi-threaded programming).

Comment: I would recommend reading this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458178/iphone-dealloc-release-vs-nil/2371133#2371133

Comment: Is it possible that the answer will depend on how the setters and getters are implemented/synthesized?

Comment: Yes - good note. nonatomic was omitted for brevity.

Comment: Thanks - that's a great read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `self.myStr = nil` and `[myStr release]` ultimately do the same thing.

Calling `[myStr release]` is obvious and just releases it.

Meanwhile, the setter method for myStr looks *roughly* like this:

```
- (void)setMyStr:(NSString *)newMyStr
{
    [newMyStr retain];
    [myStr release];
    myStr = newMyStr;
}
```

So when we do `self.myStr = nil`, we're first retaining a nil object, which does nothing. Then we release the old variable, which is what we want. Finally, we set the pointer to nil.

What's the difference? The latter sets the pointer to nil. This is better because if we (accidentally) send a message to the released object, we crash if the pointer isn't nil (EXC_BAD_ACCESS). Now honestly, since you're in -dealloc, the object is being destroyed anyways, so it wouldn't really matter what you use.

Comment: This answers my original question for synthesized setters & getters.
It is clear to me though, that for custom setters or different property attributes the answer may vary. Remover's response was also very helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458178/iphone-dealloc-release-vs-nil/2371133#2371133
Thanks for responses!

Answer (score 0):

Your dealloc should be this:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [_iVarStr release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Although setting the property to nil is possible, I worry about unintended side effects or KVO actions triggered by the change that may not realize the object is currently being deallocated.

Comment: Please explain why that is asking for trouble.

Comment: Example indicating why you should use property setters in `dealloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721#192852

Comment: Never say never.  Sometimes, setting properties in a dealloc makes sense (especially when the setter has some important side effect, such as setting up an observer).

Comment: Yes, please explain more.  regarding memory management, if you evaluate _iVarStr != nil after the release, it returns false.  That is not so with self.myStr = nil.

Comment: If your setter had a lot of side effects you should not have used a property to begin with. Any side effect the setter has can only be bad, after all you are setting the "new value" to nil and about to release the whole object.  The real trouble is that the setter change could fire off a KVC notification to some observer who would then try to act on an object mostly or partly deallocated.  

If you have a notification set up then you need to explicitly remove yourself as an observer in dealloc and not rely on side effects to do that for you.

Comment: All good points --- I retract the "never" since that does not cover all cases.... editing it to add some of these points.

Comment: In the case of needing to clean up the object (remove observers, etc), I tend to think that logic should go before the release statements.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `self.ivar=nil`(the code `ivar=nil` previously I wrote was wrong) way in dealloc method. Because, if the ivar's property change from retain to assign (or from assign to retain), you don't have to change your code.

Comment: If your ivars are `assign`, then you have to be extra careful that your objects aren't deallocated from underneath you.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me because just setting the internal ivar to nil does not release it - that makes sense for an assign property but not retain.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The exact way is `self.ivar=nil`. only `ivar=nil` is bad.

Answer (score 0):

When a property is set to retain then

```
self.ivar = nil;
```

will properly manage the memory allocation.  For other property types check the  at the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) page.  It also has a bunch of sample code so you can understand what happens "under the hood" for all the options.

Comment: Yes.  The code listed in Saurabh's answer is pretty close to the synthesized transformer.