# release Vs nil -- Best Practice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When we assign memory to a class variable, should we release it or set it to nil in dealloc method? What is the best practice?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "class variable"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Best practice:**

```
[foo release]; // ensures that memory is released
foo = nil; // ensures that there is no dangling pointer to released memory
```

**Other notes:**

When you assign to a property declared to retain,

```
// in your .h
@property (retain) MyObject *foo;

// in your .m
self.foo = bar; // bar is retained; whatever foo previously pointed at is released
```

it will release what it was previously pointing at and retain the new object being assigned.

So, you can use:

```
self.foo = nil;
```

and it will release whatever foo was pointing at. **However,** if your property was not declared to have retain storage semantics, this will not implicitly release whatever foo was pointing at. Also, as Ryan pointed out, a property can be overridden to have side effects. For this reason, it is best to follow the pattern of always using:

```
[foo release];
```

To ensure that you don't have a dangling pointer to released memory, you can follow this up with:

```
foo = nil;
```

If you are not using properties with retain semantics, you **need** to release whatever was stored in the variable:

```
[foo release];
```

---

**EDIT:** Also see the following answer to another question that explains this:

[iPhone - dealloc - Release vs. nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458178/iphone-dealloc-release-vs-nil/1458202#1458202)

Comment: It is safer to always use -release instead of the property setter, as setters can be overridden to have side-effects.  You don't want side-effects happening in your dealloc method.

Comment: Also, this blog post clarified a great deal for me http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/1423/dont-coddle-your-code

Comment: I've often found that explicitly assigning `nil` after the release can mask bugs. It's a bug if anyone is accessing the ivar afterwards, and assigning `nil` both allows this to succeed without any apparent error and prevents the usage of any of the memory debugging tools.

Comment: Great answer - At first I did this: 

[self.myVar release]; self.myVar = nil;

This caused a crash in the dealloc section of myVar, it was being released twice>
However is I bypass the property, and simply do 
[myVar release]
myVar = nil;

All is fine. Why did the first method not work?