# Dealloc when using Storyboard in Xcode 4.2.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, null, dealloc

I found a somewhat related question at [iPhone - dealloc - Release vs. nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458178/iphone-dealloc-release-vs-nil), but it didn't answer my question.

I created a button, a `UIScrollview`, and a label inside of it in the storyboard. When I Ctrl-dragged the objects to ViewController.h they created this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    __weak IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *goButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;

- (IBAction)pressGo:(id)sender;

@end
```

And at the top of ViewController.m I have:

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize goButton;

@synthesize label;

@synthesize scroller;
```

And in `viewDidUnload` it created:

```
[self setGoButton:nil];

[self setScroller:nil];

[self setLabel:nil];

scroller = nil;

[super viewDidUnload];
```

All created automatically. I've seen many references to `dealloc` and `release`.
Will this code, the premade stuff, prevent memory leaks? Or must I add `dealloc`?
I apologize for any errors I have made... I'm new to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should IBOutlets be strong or weak under ARC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If IBOutlet are marked as weak, there's no need of setting them to nil in viewDidLoad.
If you are compiling with ARC there's also no need of writing dealloc, in any case the compiler itself is going to give you error if you write any dealloc or release statement.

With Xcode 4 ARC being default option, if you make sure of that your code is memory safe.

Comment: So there is no need to release weak objects?